# object reference not set to an instance of an object in Python VS2013 for Windows Desktop with Update 4

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed this version of VS2013 for windows desktop with update 4. and installed Python tools.

But when I tried to run a simple `print('Hello World')` A dialog box appeared containing this error message `object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I wonder why do I get this error message? I'm new to python. Do I missed some settings? Configuration? Etc? for it not to get work? I know some of you might raise an eyebrows but I really need your help, I didn't know why I got this error whenever I tried to run the `print('Hello World')`. Can somebody help me here please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I encountered the same Issue with VS2013 and PTVS 2.2.2. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @user_na. Sorry for the late reply, and yes I did manage to solve this issue few weeks after I posted this question.
All I have to do is to modify the installation process, then VOILA! It worked like magic eversince. ;)

Comment: I gave up and used another dev environment. But I just got a new hardware, maybe it would be worth to try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be encountering an issue that has been fixed in the [latest release](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2) of Python Tools, so I would suggest upgrading to see if that fixes it.

It is very likely that this is a configuration issue though. In general, anything that pops up an error message is probably best to report on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues). In this case, the follow up questions will include:

- How did you install Python onto your machine?
- What version did you install?
- Where did you download it from?
- Did PTVS automatically detect it or did you have to manually enter the details (paths, directories, etc.)?
- If the latter, did you enter *all* the details or just some of them?